# Best mechanism for communicating amongst Thrift services?

Tags: thrift

I just started working with Thrift the other day for a project prototype and I have a design question:

Assume I have a set of three Thrift Services and all of them will run on the same server; for example: TenantService, UserAccountService and an AuthService. A single server will run in a cluster of machines and host all of these services.

UserAccounts belong to Tenants and therefore when a Handler method is invoked on the UserAccountService I need to query the TenantService to retrieve information about the Tenant. In a different scenario, I may need to consult the UserAccountService from the AuthService.

What is the best practice/mechanism to communicate between the Handlers on a single server? Is it simply to pass the necessary handlers into another Handler such that if AuthService relies on UserAccountService then I should just pass the UserAccountHandler implementation to the AuthHandler at the time the AuthHandler is constructed?

If that approach is not good, should I pass the Client for the other services into the appropriate handler? Is there a TTransport that does not require going out to the network; for example a local memory TTransport?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems more related to how you want to structure your services *implementations* and their dependencies, rather than to Thrift per se.

My answer on that first question would be to leave separated what is separated, and keep together what belongs together. What do I mean by that?

- If the services are sharing one implementation, e.g. they are implemented within the same module or process, it may be better to call the implementation of a depending service directly rather than via the Thrift service interface. Although the latter would work, it seems to be unecessary overhead. Given that scenario, whether or not it makes sense to pass one handler implementation to the other, depends on how you want to use it.
- If the services are separated, because you plan to distribute them across multiple processes and/or machines later, keep them separated and just call service B from service A. In that scenario, I would consequently not establish any additional dependencies between the handlers, because that may become a blocker later on.

Of course, as always the details depend on the exact circumstances. You may also want to have a look at the [multiplex protocol](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-563) which enables you to offer multiple services over one single endpoint.

> TTransport that does not require going out to the network; for example a local memory TTransport?

Since you did not specify a language, I can only give the generic answer: Yes. There are memory transports and stream transports available for various languages, but not everything is implemented for every language yet. However, writing a transport implementation is not that hard, so if all else fails, you can do it on your own without investing too much time.